# Getting POST values from form elements added dynamically through echo statements?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, sql

In my HTML code I have a table but with no data rows initially loaded, only a header and column labels. Upon clicking a button, a number of rows are loaded into this table depending how many rows are selected from the database in a SQL statement. In this situation, if my team has seven registered players in the database, my table will display seven rows (via PHP echo statements). In each row I have a checkbox with the players name and text input boxes.

This is the jQuery that adds rows once the **post-result** button is clicked:

```
$("#post-result").click(function(){
        $("#post-result").hide();
        $("#confirm-result").show();
        $("#cancel").show();

        $("#home-player-count").show();
        $("#home-score").html("<input class='form-input f-score' id='home-score-input' type=number name=home_score maxlength=2>");
        $("#away-score").html("<input class='form-input f-score' id='away-score-input' type=number name=away_score maxlength=2>");

        $("#stats-home").after(<?php
                                echo "\"";      
                                    $i = 0;
                                    $sql2 = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM user_accounts WHERE ps4_club= '" . $myclub . "'");
                                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql2, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
                                    {
                                    $i++;
                                    echo "<tr id='player-".$i."'><td class='match-stats-name'><input type='checkbox' class='f-player' checked='true' value='" . $row['username'] . "' name='home_player_".$i."'>". $row['username'] ."";
                                    echo "<td><input class='form-input f-stats single' maxlength=1 name='home_player_".$i."_rating_1'> . <input class='form-input f-stats single' maxlength=1 name='home_player_".$i."_rating_2'></td>";
                                    echo "<td><input class='form-input f-stats single' maxlength=1 name='home_player_".$i."_goals'></td>";
                                    echo "<td><input class='form-input f-stats single' maxlength=1 name='home_player_".$i."_assists'></td>";
                                    echo "<td><input class='form-input f-stats' maxlength=2 name='home_player_".$i."_tackles_won'> / <input class='form-input f-stats' maxlength=2 name='home_player_".$i."_tackles_made'></td></tr>";
                                    }
                                echo "\"";
                                ?>)

    <?php
    $_SESSION["match_id"] = $id;
    $_SESSION["player_count"] = $i;
    $_SESSION["team"] = $team;
    ?>
```

**$("#stats-home").after** is where the rows get added.

The problem I'm coming across is when I'm trying to input this data from the table into my database. This is the bit of PHP code that is loaded once I click the **confirm-result** button of my form:

```
<?php
include "../config.php";
if (isset($_POST["confirm_result"]))
{
    session_start();

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $_SESSION["player_count"]; $i++) 
    {   
        $sql = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO ps4_apl_1_stats (match_id, team, name, rating, goals, assists, tackles_won, tackles_made)
        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $sql->bind_param("issiiiii", $match_id, $team, $name, $rating, $goals, $assists, $tackles_won, $tackles_made);

        $match_id = $_SESSION["match_id"];
        $team = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_SESSION["team"]);
        $name = "test_".$i."_player";
        $rating = $_POST["home_player_".$i."_rating_1"];
        $goals = $_POST["home_player_".$i."_goals"];
        $assists = $_POST["home_player_".$i."_assists"];
        $tackles_won = $_POST["home_player_".$i."_tackles_won"];
        $tackles_made = $_POST["home_player_".$i."_tackles_made"];

        $sql->execute();

        $sql->free_result();
    }

    header("Location: ../match.php?id=".$_SESSION['match_id']);
}
else
{
    header("Location: ../match.php?id=".$_SESSION['match_id']);
}
?>
```

What this code does is it loops through each row in the table by incrementing the $i variable. In each iteration it'll put the data from the input boxes into variables, which are then placed into the prepared SQL statement. Each row's input boxes have names that are numbered by what row number they are, for example:

ROW 1: home_player_1_goals, home_player_1_assists

ROW 2: home_player_2_goals, home_player_2_assists

ROW 3: home_player_3_goals, home_player_3_assists

When I try to submit this form, I get a lot of "Unidentified index" notices, like this:

**Notice: Undefined index: home_player_1_goals in C:\Apache24\htdocs\script\match_post.php on line 20**

For some reason it's not finding the POST variables of any of the input boxes that were inserted dynamically into the page via echo statements. It has no trouble finding $_POST["confirm_result"] since that input box is loaded into the page right at the beginning.

How do I get around this? It's pretty much not recognizing any of the input boxes that have been loaded in via echo statements.

I also dumped the $SESSION and $POST variables using print_r:

**print_r($_SESSION):** Array ( [email] => my_email@hotmail.com [userid] => 43 [xbox_club] => [ps4_club] => Wrecking Crew [match_id] => 3 [player_count] => 7 [team] => home )

**print_r($_POST):** Array ( [confirm_result] => Confirm Result )

It only shows the confirm_result button which is loaded onto the page initially.

I also have another question:

How would I go about skipping the insertion of a row depending on if it's checked or not? In each row I have a checkbox. When this checkbox is disabled, that rows input boxes will all be disabled. What would be the best way to skip this row? At the moment my code goes through every single row and enters the data, regardless of whether the input boxes are disabled or not.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE - here is a single row that gets generated after the "post-results" button is clicked:**

```
<tr id="player-1">
<td class="match-stats-name"><input type="checkbox" name="home_player_1" value="Syrian2nv" checked="true" class="f-player">Syrian2nv</td>
<td><input name="home_player_1_rating_1" maxlength="1" class="form-input f-stats single"> . <input name="home_player_1_rating_2" maxlength="1" class="form-input f-stats single"></td>
<td><input name="home_player_1_goals" maxlength="1" class="form-input f-stats single"></td>
<td><input name="home_player_1_assists" maxlength="1" class="form-input f-stats single"></td>
<td><input name="home_player_1_tackles_won" maxlength="2" class="form-input f-stats"> / <input name="home_player_1_tackles_made" maxlength="2" class="form-input f-stats"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: what does `print_r($_SESSION)` and `print_r($_POST)` say on the page that handles your post request?

Comment: $_SESSION: Array ( [email] => my_email@hotmail.com [userid] => 43 [xbox_club] => [ps4_club] => Wrecking Crew [match_id] => 3 [player_count] => 7 [team] => home ) 


$_POST: Array ( [confirm_result] => Confirm Result )

Comment: Are your inputs all inside the form tags?  This happened to me once when I put the closing form tag too soon.

Comment: Actually disabled (i.e. disabled="disabled") inputs will not be posted.

Comment: Yep I've made sure my form tags are around the table. And yeah I just assumed that they would still be posted. My code still runs through each row so it may give me errors if it doesn't find an input because it's disabled. I need a way to completely skip rows if they're disabled.

Comment: Have you used firebug or something similar to look at the HTML after the jQuery runs to make sure it looks like you think it's going to look?

Comment: Yep I've tested it with Firebug after running the jQuery and it all looks right. All the names of the input boxes are correct and the layout is the way it's supposed to be.

Comment: Put in a input like when you put in the rest with jQuery `'<input type="hidden" name="justChecking[]" value="something">` Then check for that input `if(isset($_POST['justChecking']) {echo 'works';}else{echo 'Nope';}`. If it's not there, there is something malformed with the form itself. Like the form tag isn't closed correctly or the action is set something little like that that will make you pull your hair out.

Comment: Yeah adding that input straight into the page when it first loads will work. It echos "Works" and my $_POST array has [justChecking] => something. For some reason the inputs that are loaded in dynamically with "echo" are not recognized.

Comment: Yea, load it dynamically that's where the problem is. Also if you are using Chrome open the developer tools and go to elements. Right click on your form, so the <form> tag, no need to expand it,  and pick "copy as html" then paste that in here. Do all this of course after the jQuery insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is your form in relation to `#stats-home`? You're telling jQuery to add those form inputs **after** it, so if your form is inside it, they will miss the form.

If I were you, I would simplify the whole jQuery call you've got up there by outputting your fields when you load your page normally, but applying a class to the table row which you will tell to be invisible:

```
echo "<tr class='player-information' id='player-".$i."'><td class='match-stats-name'><input type='checkbox' class='f-player' checked='true' value='" . $row['username'] . "' name='home_player_".$i."'>". $row['username'] ."";

<style type="text/css">
.player-information {
    display: none;
}
</style>
```

Then in your jQuery you replace `$("#stats-home").after()` with:

```
$('tr.player-information').show();
```

Not sure if this will fix your problem or not, but at least you'll know that your form elements are there, in the DOM and being output in the correct place (p.s. if this doesn't help, post the resulting HTML output on your page **after** you click your button so we can see what's happening)

--edit-- also, post the javascript produced when you load the page i.e. after PHP's done its thing

Comment: My form tags are placed before and after the table. I've updated my question with the output of a single row in my HTML code. Look at the bottom of the post.

Comment: I revisited this problem and decided to use your solution. I had to redo a lot of things but it was worth it in the end. It works now. I've accepted your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer the second question. As far as the first one I'm betting that the html isn't quite right after the jQuery insert based on the fact that the var_dump on the $_POST is empty.

The second question, skip a row if the checkbox isn't checked. So if your html is like this:

```
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="checkme[]"></td>
<td><input type="text" name = "homePlayerRating[]"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="homePlayerGoals[]"></td>

</tr>

<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="checkme[]"></td>
<td><input type="text" name = "homePlayerRating[]"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="homePlayerGoals[]"></td>
</tr>
```

Then in the php when you process it do:

```
foreach($_POST['homePlayerRating'] as $key=>$homePlayerRating){
    if(isset($_POST['checkme'][$key])){
        //now you know that row was checked
        $playerRating = $_POST['homePlayerRating'][$key];
        $goals = $_POST['homePlayerGoals'][$key];
    }
 }
```

**EDIT: This is dead wrong. I'm not sure what I was thinking.** The `$_POST['checkme']` array won't match the rest of the line. It isn't added to the $_POST array if it's not checked. For example if you check the checkbox in the third line down the

```
$_POST['homePlayerTating']
```

key will 2 but the

```
$_POST['checkme']
```

key will be zero because it isn't added to that array unless it's checked so it will be the first item in the `$_POST['checkme']` array.

Comment: Cool, once I've figured out the first issue I'll try this. Thanks!

Comment: @samer.j92 I steered you completely wrong. Check out my edit before you follow any of my stupid advice.